# saving options on html5's canvas

Tags: html, canvas

I'm using this two libraries in order to save a canvas draw:

http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/canvas2image.js http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/base64.js

...and they work great however, I was wondering if there's a way to specify the name of the output file?

Comment: What name does it default to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use `Content-Disposition` header to specify a filename.

I don't think you can set that in JavaScript. But if you can, set it and use the `filename=` option to specify a default filename.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it with "download" attribute of an  element, which looks like the code below:

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" download="testXXX.jpg">DOWNLOAD ME!</a>
```

You can change the "href" attribute to data url.

Eric has [a very good tutorial](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download) on this.